# Highlight column in Vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to highlight the 80 character column in vim to help me keep my code short.
I've added this to my .vimrc:

```
" Highlight column 80
if exists('+colorcolumn')
  highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=4
  set colorcolumn=80
else
  au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
endif
```

I've looked at the available colors with `:help ctermbg` but no matter what argument I use for ctermbg, I get a dark red highlight which is very annoying. how can I change this color?

Many thanks

Comment: What does `:hi ColorColumn` print?

Comment: And why aren't you defining / using the same `ColorColumn` group in the fallback? It would be more consistent.

Comment: Ok this is a good start:
:hi ColorColumn
ColorColumn    xxx term=reverse ctermbg=4 guibg=DarkRed

How can I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an output of

```
ColorColumn xxx term=reverse ctermbg=4 guibg=DarkRed
```

you're probably using GVIM, which uses the `gui..=` definitions. You need (and should always do, unless you're solely using terminal or graphical Vim) add GUI definitions (`:h gui-colors` has a list):

```
:highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=4 guibg=blue
```

Especially if you're switching *colorschemes*, there may also be left-over attributes from that. It's safer to specify *all* attributes (see `:help :hi`):

```
:highlight ColorColumn term=reverse cterm=NONE ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=4 gui=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Try for example:

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=Blue
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Although not explicitly stated in the accepted answer, the position of where the commands are placed in the configuration files is important.
It was alluded to, but not exactly stated.
If the desire result is not seen in gvim, then try adding the lines
:highlight ColorColumn guibg=blue
at the end of the ~/.gvimrc file, after the colorsheme has been set.
Similarly at the end of ~/.vimrc add
:highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=4